# Call cqlsh in python script to execute file specified in -f option in cassandra

Tags: python, cassandra, cqlsh

How to call cqlsh script in python to execute queries in cassandra ?

Thanks, 
Imran khan

Answer (score 0):

We can use cassandra-driver  like any another db driver in python to execute cqlsh.

or

```
import cql
con= cql.connect(host="server",port=port,keyspace="keyspace")
cur=con.cursor()
result=cur.execute("select * from table")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with the `subprocess` library:

```
import subprocess
import sys

hostname=sys.argv[1]
username=sys.argv[2]
password=sys.argv[3]

strFile = "myCommands.cql"
process = subprocess.Popen("/usr/local/apache-cassandra-3.1.4/bin/cqlsh {0} -u {1} -p {2} -f {3} ;".format(hostname,username,password,strFile), shell=True)
exitCode = process.wait()
```

Give that a try.  I've done something similar to automate the COPY TO/FROM functionality.

Do note that your `cql` command file will need to have commands terminated with a semi-colon (`;`), just like you would within cqlsh.